# Always oddly-many ones in the binary expression for $10^{10^{n}}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computer-science, discrete-mathematics

**Update**: Pending independent verification, the answer to the title question is "**no**", according to a computation of $q(10) = 11609679812$ (which is *even*).

Let $q(n)$ be the number of ones in the binary expression for $10^{10^{n}}$ (which is the same as for $5^{10^{n}}$ of course), for positive integer $n$. The first nine $q(n)$ values — the most I can compute — are all odd: $11, 105, 1163, 11683, 115979, 1161413, 11606847, 116093517, 1160951533$. Is this just a quirk (with even values showing up eventually), or is $q(n)$ odd for all positive integer $n$? Equivalently, letting $t(0),t(1),t(2)...$ be the [Thue-Morse sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence), is $t(10^{10^{n}}) = 1$ for all positive integer $n$?

It may not be surprising that *about* half of the binary digits of $5^{10^{n}}$ are ones, i.e., $q(n) \sim \displaystyle\frac{1}{2} \log_2(5^{10^{n}}) \approx \ 1.16096404744 \cdot 10^{n}$ (thus explaining the leading digits of sufficiently large terms), but why should all the terms be odd (if indeed they are)?

Note: My motivation for posting is the expectation that a proposition like "$q(10^{10})$ is even" provides a problem of the kind that Solomon Feferman (["Are there absolutely unsolvable problems?"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.156.6181), p. 16), calls "absolutely unsolvable from the standpoint of practice". Obviously, this expectation is wrong if it can be proved that $q(n)$ is odd for all positive integer $n$. I strongly suspect, however, that there are infinitely many $q(n)$ values of each parity.

Comment: whoops, you're right.

Comment: I'd mention http://oeis.org/A118738, but it doesn't seem to have any information.

Comment: Could you describe how you got up to $n=9$? When I take the direct approach and calculate the powers using Java's BigInteger class, already $n=7$ takes a long time; I'd presume that they use efficient methods to calculate the powers; are you doing something more sophisticated?

Comment: @joriki: I imagine r.e.s. is using Fast Fourier Transforms. I would be surprised if FFT was built into the BigInteger class.

Comment: @joriki: I used a [Sage](http://sagemath.org) notebook with `def q(n): return bin(5^(10^n)).count('1')`, which took less than a minute.

Comment: On the other hand, I would not be at all surprised if FFT was built into Sage.

Comment: I just updated the question with results of a computation of $q(10)$ (which is *even*, if the computation is correct). Being new to SE, I wasn't sure just how to present this in the body of the question. I'm happy to explain the computation details, of course, but I don't know whether this would be the right place for it. Or should I just write it into an answer to my own question?

Comment: Writing an answer to your own question is fine. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/what-to-do-if-you-figure-out-the-answer-to-your-own-question

Comment: @r.e.s.: By all means give us a few details on how you carried out the computation. Especially as joriki specifically asked you about it!

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Thanks for the advice and link.

Comment: @TonyK: Well, I hope I haven't overdone the detail in my answer concerning $q(10)$.

Comment: See also this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @joriki: That linked post is very encouraging ... thank you.

Comment: Feferman's article asserts that the question 
"Is the value of the digit in the $10^{10^{10^{10}}}$th place of the decimal expansion of $\pi - 3$ equal to $0$?" "cannot be settled by the human mind because it is beyond all remotely conceivable computational power on the one hand and *there is no conceptual foothold to settle it by a proof* on the other." My motivating question is whether exactly the same is true of the question 
"Are there evenly many ones in the binary expression for $10^{10^{10^{10}}}$?" -- or does $\pi$ have some special quality that sets it apart in this regard?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer to the title question is "**no**" according to the following computation in a [Sage notebook](http://sagemath.org/):

```
%time
for n in [1..10]: print n, (5^10^n).popcount()

 1 11
 2 105
 3 1163
 4 11683
 5 115979
 6 1161413
 7 11606847
 8 116093517
 9 1160951533
10 11609679812

CPU time: 487.60 s,  Wall time: 1935.41 s
```

EDIT: In Sage, the popcount() method -- which returns the number of ones in the binary representation -- is built-in for objects of type 'Integer' (but *not* for type 'long', which I had been forcing), making it unnecessary to import gmpy, etc., as done previously.

Comment: Just one (hopefully-obvious) comment: you may want to use the 'hybrid' approach through gmpy (and the bin counting) on the previous problem instances to confirm that the results you get match the already-known results...

Comment: Yes, I already did that, and they agree.