# $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\frac{\text{number of 1s in the binary numeral of }b^n}{n}) = \log_4(\text{OddPart}(b))$, for any positive integer b?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, binary

**Notation**: For any positive integer $x$, let $\operatorname{Ones}(x)$ denote the [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) of $x$ (i.e., the number of $1$s in the binary numeral for $x$), and let $\operatorname{OddPart}(x)$ denote the [odd part](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddPart.html) of $x$ (i.e. the largest odd divisor of $x$).

While computing some Hamming weights, I was surprised to see the following behavior: It seems that *for any given positive integer $b$, $\operatorname{Ones}(b^{(10^k)})$ has the same leading decimal digits for all sufficiently large $k$*. Furthermore (with help of OEIS), these leading digits are discovered to be those of $\log_4\operatorname{OddPart}(b)$ in every case except when $b$ is a power of two (in which case there is of course only one $1$ in the numeral of $b$).

**Examples**: It's only necessary to look at odd $b$ because $\operatorname{Ones}(b^n) = \operatorname{Ones}(\operatorname{(OddPart}(b))^n),$ since multiplying by a power of two just appends $0$s to the binary numeral.

```
   b     Ones(b^10^9)   Ones(b^10^9)/10^9 ≈ log_4(b)
----------------------------------------------------
   1               1         0.0000          0.0000
   3       792490796         0.7925          0.7925
   5      1160951533         1.1610          1.1610
   7      1403656246         1.4037          1.4037
   9      1584925047         1.5849          1.5850
  11      1729722034         1.7297          1.7297
  13      1850206247         1.8502          1.8502
  15      1953457439         1.9535          1.9534
 123      3471255304         3.4713          3.4713
4567      6078486804         6.0785          6.0785
```

Numerically, the same behavior is found to occur for ${\operatorname{Ones}(b^n)\over n}$ with sufficiently large $n$ not necessarily a power of ten, leading to the following conjecture:

> For any positive integer $b$, $$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}{\operatorname{Ones}(b^n)\over n}= \log_4 \operatorname{OddPart}(b).$$

**Question**: Can someone suggest how to prove this, and/or provide a source in the literature?

(There is a slightly related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/70094/16397).)

---

SageMath code for the above table:

```
for b in [1 .. 15, step=2] + [123, 4567]:
    if is_odd(b):
        ones = (b**10**9).popcount()
        print(f"{b:4} {ones:12} {float(ones/10**9):7.4f} {float(log(b,4)):7.4f}")
```

---

**Update** (12/18/2022):

The "random digits" heuristic described in the comment by @HagenvonEitzen lends plausibility to the following more general conjectures, which do indeed appear to be borne out numerically (using SageMath):

> For positive integers $p, x$, define
>
> - $N_p(x)\overset{def}{=}$ the number of nonzero digits in the base-$p$ numeral for $x$,
> - $S_p(x)\overset{def}{=}$ the sum of all the digits in the base-$p$ numeral for $x$.
> - $R_p(x)\overset{def}{=}$ the result of dividing $x$ by the largest power of $p$ that divides $x.$
> - $Z_p(x)\overset{def}{=}\min\left({e_1^\prime\over e_1},\ldots,{e_k^\prime\over e_k}\right),$ where in standard form the prime factorization of $p$ is $p=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{e_i}$, and $e_i^\prime$ is the exponent of $p_i$ in the prime factorization of $x$.
>
> **Claim**:
> If $p, b$ are positive integers, then
>
> 1. $$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}{N_p(b^n)\over n}= {p-1\over p}\big(\log_p(R_p(b))-Z_p(R_p(b))\big).$$
> 2. $$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}{S_p(b^n)\over n}= {p-1\over 2}\big(\log_p(R_p(b))-Z_p(R_p(b))\big).$$

The reasoning is as follows, where we let $r=R_p(b)$:

- $r$ is just the result of removing all trailing $0$s (if any) from the base-$p$ numeral of $b$, which affects neither the number of nonzero digits nor the sum of all the digits; hence, $N_p(b^n)=N_p(r^n)$ and $S_p(b^n)=S_p(r^n)$.
- Now some of the base-$p$ digits of $r^n$ may also be trailing $0$s. This number (say $z\ge 0$) is the largest $m$ such that $p^m$ divides $r^n$, which is seen to be the largest $m$ such that $m e_i\le n e_i^\prime$ for all $i\in 1..k,$ where the $e_i$ are the exponents in the prime factorization of $p=\prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{e_i}$ and $e_i^\prime$ is the exponent of $p_i$ in the prime factorization of $r$.  Thus $z$ is the largest $m$ such that $m\le n Z_p(r);$  hence, $z\sim n Z_p(r)$ as $n\to\infty$.

  Example: $p=2^3 5^7, (e_1,e_2)=(3,7);r=2^1 3^3 5^2,(e_1^\prime,e_2^\prime)=(1,2);Z_p(r)=\min(1/3,2/7)=2/7.$
- Hence, (number of base-$p$ digits of $b^n$ **that are not trailing $0$s**) $\sim n \log_p(r)- n Z_p(r).$
- *If the digits that are not trailing zeros tend to occur with approximately equal frequencies*, then we obtain the above results (1) and (2):

  $$N_p(r^n)\sim n\ \big(\log_p(r)- Z_p(r)\big)\ {p-1\over p}$$
  and
  $$S_p(r^n)\sim n\ \big(\log_p(r)- Z_p(r)\big){0+1+2+...+(p-1)\over p}=n\ \big(\log_p(r)- Z_p(r)\big)\ {p-1\over 2}.$$
- Note that $Z_p(r)=0$ iff some prime divisor of $p$ is not a divisor of $r$.

Comment: Since $b$ has $\log_2(b)=2\log_4(b)$ binary digits, this boils down to: $b^n$ is random enough to have approximately as many $1$'s as $0$'s in the range where we do not know fro trivial reasons that the digits are $0$. Sounds at least plausible.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I like that heuristic -- nicely intuitive. (It makes me wonder, though, whether an actual proof might be as difficult as something like proving the normality of pi.)